# W3C validation error: "Attribute name not allowed on element meta at this point."

Tags: html, meta, w3c-validation

Any idea what this issue means and how I can fix it in WordPress?

> Error: Attribute name not allowed on element meta at this point.
>
> From line 211, column 2; to line 211, column 54
>
> ```
> </div>↩   <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">↩  </he
> ```
>
> Attributes for element meta:
>
> Global attributes
>
> - name
> - http-equiv
> - content
> - charset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `div` tag in the `head` of your document, that will cause an error.